# Unable to login in gtalk using smack in java in remote server

Tags: java, xmpp, smack

I am using `smack 3.2.2` in a web app to send message from one Gmail id to another. My app works fine in my localhost(localhost:8080/app), but when I put it in remote server (www.example.com:8080/App) it shows me `connection.getUser()` is null and `login fail because of username and password is incorrect`. But if username and password was incorrect, how can it works in my localhost? It also throws

> org.jivesoftware.smack.sasl.SASLErrorException: SASLError using PLAIN:
>   not-authorized

exception. Same code works in localhost but not in remote server.

> connConfig = new ConnectionConfiguration("talk.google.com", 5222,
>                 "gmail.com");
>   connection = new XMPPConnection(connConfig);
>   connection.connect();
>
> connConfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(false);
>   SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("PLAIN", 0);
>
> connection.login(username, password);

and also got

```
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.XHTMLManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.LastActivityManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.commands.AdHocCommandManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.ServiceDiscoveryManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.XHTMLManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.muc.MultiUserChat
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.ibb.InBandBytestreamManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.bytestreams.socks5.Socks5BytestreamManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.filetransfer.FileTransferManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.LastActivityManager
Error! A startup class specified in smack-config.xml could not be loaded: org.jivesoftware.smackx.commands.AdHocCommandManager
forbidden(403) Username or password not correct.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.NonSASLAuthentication.authenticate(NonSASLAuthentication.java:109)
```

Comment: You need org.jivesoftware.smackx-3.1.0.jar on your classpath.

Comment: I  already added jar file on classpath using eclipse and then export it to war file and put the war file to remote server tomcat>webapp folder. did i need to run add classpath commant on remote server?

Comment: I got my solution. https://accounts.google.com/DisplayUnlockCaptcha